# enable my parent main window(parent window) after closing my chlid window

Tags: c#, wpf

I want enable my parent window on closing of child window. When i use enable property it doesn't work for me.  form parent to child it works, my parent window disabled.

Comment: Have you considered posting code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In parent `Window`:

```
childWindow.Closed += ChildWindowClosed;

...

private void ChildWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Now, when the child `Window` closes, the parent `Window.IsEnabled` property will be set to `true`.

However, you probably shouldn't do this anyway... there could be negative consequences to disabling the main `Window`. If you just want to temporarily 'lock' the parent `Window` while the child `Window` is open, then all you have to do is to open the child `Window` as a dialog, like this instead:

```
childWindow.ShowDialog();
```